# Assistance with SQL Commands

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

I am trying to create a simple form that connects to my SQL database an runs a SQL select query.

If I use a simple query like "select * from users" the datagrid is populated and the data is present. My query is a lot more advanced and doesn't appear to be working. I get a lot of Syntax errors and a "sql command does not contain a constructor that takes 31 arguments". I'm sure i am doing something incredible wrong.

SQL Query - Works in SQL management studio.

```
SELECT sdk.EventsEx.EventTime AS 'Date/Time',
       sdk.UsersEx.Field14_50 AS 'Personnel Number',
CONCAT(sdk.EventsEx.Surname, ', ', sdk.EventsEx.FirstName) as 'User',
             sdk.EventsEx.CardNumber AS 'Token Number',
             sdk.EventsEx.PeripheralName AS 'Where',
             sdk.EventsEx.EventTypeDescription AS 'Event',
CONCAT(sdk.EventsEx.EventSubTypeDescription, ' ', sdk.EventsEx.EventDetails) as 'Details'

FROM         sdk.EventsEx INNER JOIN
             sdk.UsersEx ON sdk.EventsEx.UserID = sdk.UsersEx.UserID

WHERE(sdk.EventsEx.UserID > -1)
and Field14_50 = 'PN32701'

ORDER BY [Date/Time] DESC
```

C# Code

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnConnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            using (DataTable dt = new DataTable("Users"))
            {
                using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cn"].ConnectionString))

                {
                    if (cn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                        cn.Open();
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand

                        ("SELECT sdk.EventsEx.EventTime AS 'Date/Time',
                                 sdk.UsersEx.Field14_50 AS 'Personnel Number',
                    CONCAT(sdk.EventsEx.Surname, ', ', sdk.EventsEx.FirstName) as 'User',
                                 sdk.EventsEx.CardNumber AS 'Token Number',
                                 sdk.EventsEx.PeripheralName AS 'Where',
                                 sdk.EventsEx.EventTypeDescription AS 'Event',
                    CONCAT(sdk.EventsEx.EventSubTypeDescription, ' ', sdk.EventsEx.EventDetails) as 'Details'

                    FROM         sdk.EventsEx INNER JOIN
                                 sdk.UsersEx ON sdk.EventsEx.UserID = sdk.UsersEx.UserID

                    WHERE(sdk.EventsEx.UserID > -1)
                    and Field14_50 = 'PN32701'

                    ORDER BY[Date / Time] DESC", cn)

                    { CommandType = CommandType.Text };
                    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                    da.Fill(dt);
                    dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
                }

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your C# code?

Comment: You cannot have multi-line string without a [`@`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/verbatim) before it.

Comment: As @juharr says, multiline strings need a `@` before them to indicate they should be treated as a *verbatim* string, like so: `(@"SELECT sdk.EventsEx.EventTime`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not *build* (concatenate the strings) but put a *verbatim string*: add `@` before `"` and paste the query as it is from your RDBMS studio into `@"";`:

```
// Verbatim string makes the query readable
string commandText = 
  @"SELECT sdk.EventsEx.EventTime AS 'Date/Time'
          ,sdk.UsersEx.Field14_50 AS 'Personnel Number'
          ,CONCAT(sdk.EventsEx.Surname, ', ', sdk.EventsEx.FirstName) AS 'User'
          ,sdk.EventsEx.CardNumber AS 'Token Number'
          ,sdk.EventsEx.PeripheralName AS 'Where'
          ,sdk.EventsEx.EventTypeDescription AS 'Event'
          ,CONCAT(sdk.EventsEx.EventSubTypeDescription, ' ', sdk.EventsEx.EventDetails) AS 'Details'
      FROM sdk.EventsEx INNER JOIN 
           sdk.UsersEx ON sdk.EventsEx.UserID = sdk.UsersEx.UserID
     WHERE (sdk.EventsEx.UserID > -1) 
       AND Field14_50 = 'PN32701'
  ORDER BY [Date/Time] DESC";
```

Then

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(commandText, cn)) {
  ... 
}
```

Comment: Even better, and neater. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try the string below. Notice the space before FROM, WHERE and ORDER

```
            string commandText = "SELECT sdk.EventsEx.EventTime AS 'Date/Time'" +
                                 ", sdk.UsersEx.Field14_50 AS 'Personnel Number'" +
                                 ",CONCAT(sdk.EventsEx.Surname, ', ', sdk.EventsEx.FirstName) as 'User'" +
                                 ",sdk.EventsEx.CardNumber AS 'Token Number'" +
                                 ",sdk.EventsEx.PeripheralName AS 'Where'" +
                                 ",sdk.EventsEx.EventTypeDescription AS 'Event'" +
                                 ",CONCAT(sdk.EventsEx.EventSubTypeDescription, ' ', sdk.EventsEx.EventDetails) as 'Details'" +
                                 " FROM sdk.EventsEx INNER JOIN sdk.UsersEx ON sdk.EventsEx.UserID = sdk.UsersEx.UserID" +
                                 " WHERE(sdk.EventsEx.UserID > -1) and Field14_50 = 'PN32701'" +
                                 " ORDER BY [Date/Time] DESC";
```

Comment: and notice the `+` to concate strings :)

Comment: *Building* a query (especially when we *have to note spaces*) makes the text difficult o read, and that;s why is not a good practice. Why not using *verbatim strings*? `string commandText = @"SELECT ... ORDER BY [Date/Time] DESC"`?

Comment: That is why I made it multiple lines so it can be read easily.  Creating a one line query make it very difficult to visualize.  The are no special characters in this query that require the '@' except the line feeds.

Comment: @jdweng: Sorry for my premature comment, a it's in order to *keep* new lines (one line queries are often real nightmires - you are quite right) I recommend verbatim strings: `@"any text here with new lines"`